# ag-grid: color cells if nearing expiration date

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid-react

Trying to color cells if the dates on the grid are expiring soon i.e. 'Survey Exp - 1/1/2020' and I want the cell to turn red when today's date is 5 months within supplier expiration. Pls help

```
        var today = new Date();
        var curr_date = today.getDate();
        var curr_month = today.getMonth() + 1;
        var curr_year = today.getFullYear();
        var todayMan = curr_month + '/' + curr_date + '/' curr_year

        class Bsall extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
        super(props) 
        this.state = {
        items: [],
        columnDefs: [

            {headerName: "Supplier Status", field: "supplier_status", sortable: true, filter: true},
            {headerName: "Survey Exp", field: "survey_exp", sortable: true, filter: true, cellStyle: 
            params => {
                if (params.value < todayMan + 5) {
                    return {'background-color': 'red'}}
                }},
```

Comment: you cannot add todayMan + 5, it becomes 07/11/20195

Comment: Would you know what can be done instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using new Date and comparing months with getMonth() from date

1. Get years difference from both dates and convert to months by multiplying with 12
   `((new Date(val).getFullYear() - new Date(todayMan).getFullYear()) * 12)`
2. Get months from both dates by getMonth() method and difference of it

   `new Date(val).getMonth() - new Date(todayMan).getMonth()`
3. Combining both will give months count between dates
4. Check if it less than 5 months and apply style

   `if (months < 5) {
                           return {'background-color': 'red'}
                       }`

Working code sample for reference - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/ZEEowMr?editors=1010